# Call all elements in an array at the same time

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program to apply an operation between all values in an array or string, however the operation is a bitwise ^ operation between all the elements. Is there anything that can do this? Between my knowledge of lists and arrays I don't even know where to start.
EX:

```
    int[] n = {0,1,2,3,4,6}
    // program that can do the operation for 0^1^2^3^4^6
```

Comment: You can't "call" elements in an array. What exactly are you trying to do? What does it mean "to apply an operation"?

Comment: Do it one by one.

Comment: you cant do it one by one because its a bitwise operation between all the elements in the array

Comment: Use a for loop. Do the first 2 numbers to get a result, then the 3rd number against the result and so on..

Comment: You either didn't try it, or you did it wrong. [It works](https://ideone.com/3gSQsE)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with arrays but you can achieve what you wanna do with the list using streams;

```
 List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,6);
 int res = l.stream().reduce(0, (m,k) -> m +k);
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind it? It would be a huge help for the future implementation.

Comment: in Java8 stream represents a sequence of objects from a source, which supports aggregate operations, reduce is one such aggregate operation, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

Comment: yeah but why does this work and making a loop supposedly doesn't? it doesn't make logical sense in that way.

Comment: @LassiKinnunen It does work, check out [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921811/call-all-elements-in-an-array-at-the-same-time#comment80817347_46921811) with an example.

Comment: Also, [`IntStream.of(int...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of-int...-) would be more efficient, avoids the unboxing.